# Can I loop through an array to change and elements attributes on hover

Tags: jquery, arrays, navigation, hover

This seems a little verbose, is there a better way of doing this?
I'm using jquery to change a navigations aria attributes from hidden=true to hidden=false on hover (same for expanded). I'm sure this can be done in far fewer lines of code but i'm not quite sure how. I can sense a thousand eyes rolling, sorry guys I'm a noob.

```
var navArray = ['#navitem1', '#navitem2', '#navitem3', '#navitem4', '#navitem5' ]
$(navArray[0]).hover(function(){
    $( navArray[0] + 'DD').attr('aria-expanded','true');
    $( navArray[0] + 'DD').attr('aria-hidden','false');
},
function(){
    $(navArray[0] + 'DD').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    $(navArray[0]+ 'DD').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
});   

 $(navArray[1]).hover(function(){
    $( navArray[1] + 'DD').attr('aria-expanded','true');
    $( navArray[1] + 'DD').attr('aria-hidden','false');
},
function(){
    $(navArray[1] + 'DD').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    $(navArray[1]+ 'DD').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
});  
  $(navArray[2]).hover(function(){
    $( navArray[2] + 'DD').attr('aria-expanded','true');
    $( navArray[2] + 'DD').attr('aria-hidden','false');
},
function(){
    $(navArray[2] + 'DD').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    $(navArray[2]+ 'DD').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
});  
   $(navArray[3]).hover(function(){
    $( navArray[3] + 'DD').attr('aria-expanded','true');
    $( navArray[3] + 'DD').attr('aria-hidden','false');
},
function(){
    $(navArray[3] + 'DD').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    $(navArray[3]+ 'DD').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
});  
   $(navArray[4]).hover(function(){
    $( navArray[4] + 'DD').attr('aria-expanded','true');
    $( navArray[4] + 'DD').attr('aria-hidden','false');
},
function(){
    $(navArray[4] + 'DD').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    $(navArray[4]+ 'DD').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
});
```

Comment: Delete the array, put a common class on all those elements, and then assign a single event handler to that class and reference the element that raised the event using `this`.

Comment: Almost Rory, but it this will add the attributes to the parent not the child. Thanks for taking the time to look thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a common class as selector then target specific element regarding the element ID, using `this`inside `hover() in/out` handler:

```
$('.nav-item').hover(function (e) {
    var toExpand = e.type === "mouseenter";
    $('#' + this.id + "DD").attr({
        "aria-expanded": toExpand,
        "aria-hidden": !toExpand,
    });
});
```

I guess intead of targeting an ID, you could use some index, depending your HTML markup.

Comment: This cracked it! Thanks very much.